# Change responsive list from horizontal to vertical CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change one list from horizontal to vertical.

Here is original list:

[image]

And i want to change the list to :

[image]

Here is link: https://www.loberon.de/Moebel/Schraenke-Regale/Schraenke/Sideboard-Yukon.html you can see exactly.

I want to known, how can i change with CSS. Thank you very much :)

P/S: The picture should be kept.

Comment: This seems to be a Slick slider, so you will likely have to change the parameters that initializes with. http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change in your js code with responsive mode:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.your-class').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: false,       
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3,
          vertical: true,
          verticalSwiping: true,
        }
      },
    ]
  });       
});
```

Here is a working code:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.your-class').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: false,       
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3,
          vertical: true,
          verticalSwiping: true,
        }
      },
    ]
  });       
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="your-class">
    <div><img src="https://static.loberon.de/out/pictures/generated/product/2/120_120_75/30552_sideboard_yukon_antikweiss.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://static.loberon.de/out/pictures/generated/product/3/120_120_75/30389_sideboard_yukon_antikweiss.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://static.loberon.de/out/pictures/generated/product/4/120_120_75/30387_sideboard_yukon_antikweiss.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://static.loberon.de/out/pictures/generated/product/5/120_120_75/30388_sideboard_yukon_antikweiss.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://static.loberon.de/out/pictures/generated/product/6/120_120_75/30671_sideboard_yukon_antikweiss.jpg"></div>
  </div>
```

You can also check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e2p4wqLs/12/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to check this with console of this page. I have tried: 

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".selectors.otherPictures.list-thumbs.slick-slider__hidden.slick-initialized.slick-slider").slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: false,       
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3,
          vertical: true,
          verticalSwiping: true,
        }
      },
    ]
  });       
});
 
But it seems not working. :(

Comment: Try to added this code in file when you initializes the slick slider.

Comment: Welcome..Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to rotate an element would be to use the **transform** operation.

```
#morePicsContainer {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate)

Comment: Thank to answer. But i want to keep this picture. This means the picture should be kept :(

Answer (score 0):

Change each of the images style properties as such:

```
display: block;
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) is a link to documentation about display types.
Hope this helps.

[Slick vertical carousel](https://codepen.io/DrizzlyOwl/pen/adZmem) codepen example which might help with this problem.

Comment: I've update my answer with a link to an example of a vertical slick carousel.

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap grid so that the on responsive it can go from horizontal to vertical

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">

</div> 
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">

</div> 
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">

</div> 
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are the working links, for vertical slider....

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Links are missing

Comment: @gerl: They were present, but the contributor didn't format them as code, and so they were being interpreted as literal HTML (or, more likely, stripped out as invalid HTML by Stack Overflow's parser). I've edited the answer to fix the issue.